# qemu: How to use resolutions > 1024x768 in Windows 8(.1)?

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1, virtualization, linux-kvm, qemu

In previous Windows versions, I was able to get higher resolutions in qemu/qemu-kvm by passing the -vga std or -vga vmware command line parameters.

However, when I try the same for Windows 8 (and 8.1), it doesn't work. I still can only select 1048x768.

I know I can use RDP to connet to the Windows virtual machine, but I would prefer a solution within the SDL window. Is there a way?